# How to classify the statement "If $n=a\cdot b$ and $a\leq b$, then $a\cdot a \leq a\cdot b = n$"? A property? inequality? formula? other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is some algebra used to help write a prime finder from an SO Q/A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr/5811176#comment33540777_5811151):

> *because if `n = a * b` and `a <= b` then `a * a <= a * b = n`.*
>
> *– [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness) Mar 1 '14 at 4:35*

It is used to create this code here:

```
// j <= Math.sqrt(i)
for(let j = 2; j * j <= i; j++){
```

However I was trying to classify this "truth".

I looked at various cheat sheets such as [this one](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/algebra-reference-sheet), and could not find any direct references to it.

The closest was the `Radical Properties` section. Is there a name for the algebraic formula above.

> How is it classified ... a property?  An equality? A formula? A derivation?

There is no `algebra` tag for this site?

Comment: As an aside, there are many different categories of 'algebra', many of which you will have never heard of and are unrelated to what you hope to describe.  'algebra-precalculus', 'elementary-number-theory' or similar might be what you are interested in.

Comment: As for why if $\color{grey}{0<}a\leq b$ then $a\cdot a \leq a\cdot b\leq b\cdot b$, that is a [basic property of inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Multiplication_and_division) and positive numbers.  More generally, if $a\leq b$ and $0<c$ then $ac\leq bc$

Comment: So I will call it a property of inequalities.  Thanks for the wikipedia link.  A property is taken as fact and there is no derivation necessary.

Comment: Uh., no.  The term "property" just refers to a piece of information that is well known.  You generally don't need to prove many properties in each context that you use it, but several properties needed proof at least once at some point in your education.  You seem to be confusing the term "property" with the term "axiom" or "definition."  Axioms and definitions never need proof.  Properties might be axioms themselves or they might be results of axioms that needed proof.

Comment: ... interesting ... the answer below is referring to an axiom.  I am presenting an equation, should I classify it as a property or an axiom ?  And what is its name ? Both your classification as a **property of inequalities** ... and the answer below classification as a **defining axiom** seem valid

Comment: Word it according to your audience.  If your audience will accept facts if you say that they are facts without any further justification, then calling it a property is fine.  If your audience is educated and have seen most basic facts presented before already, calling it a property is fine.  If your audience is critical and ask for citations for every miniscule thing and would question whether what you present as fact really is fact and ask for justification, calling it an axiom is perhaps more appropriate.  Keep in mind that lay people might not know the word "axiom" however.

Comment: partial quotation can be a misquotation. the [full quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr/5811176#comment33540777_5811151) is *"if `n = a*b` and `a <= b` then `a*a <= a*b = n`"*. this simply multiplies both parts of the inequality by `a` an then applies the equality.

Comment: (contd.) , revealing the truth of the implied conclusion, `a*a <= n`.

Comment: I thought that was a typo ... `a * a <= a * b = n `.  You are just re-iterating that `a * b = n`.  So difficult to read after coding were `=` means assignment and not equality.

Comment: @j.a. Re `why is there no algebra tag for this site`. We don't have one because that one is hopelessly generic. You are probably more interested in more specific ones: maybe [inequality] or [arithmetic] , possibly.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is that this is [a defining axiom for an ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring)

Specifically, if $c\geq 0$ and $a\leq b$, then $ac\leq bc$.  In your case I guess you are assuming $c=a\geq 0$.

There is of course a notion of [ordered group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group) too but since it looked like you were basically using integers, I chose that one above.

The definition given in wikipedia for an [ordered semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_semigroup) would be a particularly good fit if you were just considering $\mathbb N$, but I'm not familiar with it. (I'm surprised there's no positivity condition mentioned.)

Comment: +1 ... According to the comments above this is a basic property of inequalities.  Am I correct in saying this?  Or is a defining axiom more correct ?

Comment: And yes this is for integers, prime finding.

Comment: What is this alien letter ... ℕ

Comment: @j.a.  Calling it a "basic property of inequalities" is not wrong, but it does not explain that this property is a consequence of the order axioms on the integers (or natural numbers, if you prefer.) I just think it's a little more useful this way.  It is not **only** a property of the natural numbers, is what I'm getting at.  You can say the same for any ordered ring or field (namely the real numbers, or any of its subrings.)

Comment: @j.a.  $\mathbb N$ is standard notation for the nonnegative integers, and $\mathbb Z$ is standard notation for the integers.

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561080/what-is-this-algebra-called-and-how-is-it-classified/3561192#comment7324557_3561080) is the context for this, I think.

Comment: @WillNess Yes... that context is a special case of this natural one. Are you proposing I should ignore the natural one in favor of a rigid adherence to the one provided?  ( I could be misunderstanding the comment... it kind of comes out of the blue.)

Comment: proposing nothing. :) just side-noting.

Comment: @WillNess OK, just checking!  Thanks